# How to utilize this MySQL javascript code to create a database / write a query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, server

Just started to learn using nodejs and javascript to make some basic servers and databases to look at and we have this code to utilize:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
      host     : 'stusql.dcs.shef.ac.uk',
      port     : '3306',
      user     : 'USERNAME',
      password : '********',
      database : 'DBNAME'
    }
);
connection.connect();
var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM device');

query.on('error', function(err) {
    throw err;
});

query.on('fields', function(fields) {
    console.log(fields);
});

query.on('result', function(row) {
    console.log(row);
});
connection.end();
```

And from this we are supposed to now put our login and password in this code (which I have done on my version) and then *create a small database and write a query*. How do i do this part?

Do I go to the host and how do use this code to make a small database and write a query... There's no explanation and I ran this code on webstorm IDE and it runs but after a short while it throws the error from the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `mysql.js:16
    throw err;
    ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT` This is the throw err part of the code that tells it to throw error if its been waiting too long I think. I just don't know how to create a database with mySQL and also write a query given  this code do you have any idea?

Comment: Maybe your query is take too long, or maybe you have an connection issue, can you connect to the same db by using command line tool ?

Comment: how do I make a database that connects to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you can perform all the query you want, i don't see a need to create database or table dynamically. 
I use `connection.query()` for [CRUD Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) only.

**But still you can do that.See the code.**

I have added `setTimeout()` so that you can clearly see what is it happening while running the code.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var config={
      host     : 'localhost',
      port     : '3306',
      user     : 'root',
      password : 'root',
    }
var connection = mysql.createConnection();
connection.connect(config);
connection.query('drop database if exists mydb',function(err){
  if(err)
    return console.log(err);
  console.log('deleted db');

  setTimeout(function(){
    connection.query('create database if not exists mydb',function(err){
      if(err)
        return console.log(err);
      console.log('DB Created successfully');

      setTimeout(function(){
        var qstring='CREATE TABLE mydb.table1 '+
        '(id INT NOT NULL,name VARCHAR(45)'+
        ' NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id));'
        connection.query(qstring,function(err){
          if(err)
            return console.log(err);
          console.log('table created successfully');

          setTimeout(function(){
            var qstring="INSERT INTO mydb.table1 (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('1', 'abc'),('2', 'bcd'),('3','cde')"
            connection.query(qstring,function(err){
              if(err)
                return console.log(err);
              console.log('Rows added successfully');

              setTimeout(function(){
                var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM mydb.table1');

                query.on('error', function(err) {
                  throw err;
                });

                query.on('fields', function(fields) {
                  console.log(fields);
                });

                query.on('result', function(row) {
                  console.log(row);
                });
              },2000);
            });
          },2000);
        });
      },2000);
    })
  },2000);
});
```

So i guess that was what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you but could you help me more with this? I'm still really stuck. If I run your code I cannot open this on localhost:3306 the page won't load. How do I use this code to make a database?

Comment: also when i run the code I get this error: `{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true }`

Comment: ok i put the correct host now that error is gone but new error appeared bro: `{ [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT]
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }

Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: Change the user and password for your mysql

Comment: make a remote repository and add me in there!

Comment: im new to all this bro where do I make that and I add you?  you mean the phpmyadmin settings for mysql?

Comment: You know you need to have mysql username and password??

Comment: yes but where do I look at this? is it phpmyadmid with apache?

Comment: have you ever heard od mysql server??

Comment: yes talk to me in that room you invited me to im there also Im off work soon so I can talk more often then

Comment: still in the room you invited and I'm off work now so I can talk properly please help man

Comment: I can not help u in that

Comment: what do you mean? i just need an explanation on the code you provided what it means and how to get it to work